# Send Http Request from Blazor Component

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I'm using .Net Core 3.1 and I'm having trouble sending requests from a Blazor component. I want to send a request to a controller I have, and these requests systematically end up in 400 Bad request.

In my Startup.cs, I have

```
            if (!services.Any(x => x.ServiceType == typeof(HttpClient)))
            {
                services.AddScoped<HttpClient>(s =>
                {
                    var uriHelper = s.GetRequiredService<NavigationManager>();
                    return new HttpClient
                    { 
                        BaseAddress = new Uri(uriHelper.BaseUri)
                    };
                });
            }
```

In my Blazor component, I have:

```
        var json2 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_Model);
        var stringContent2 = new StringContent(json2, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var response2 = await Http.PostAsync("/[controllerName]/[Method]", stringContent2);

        if (response2.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var resultContent = response2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            return resultContent;
        }
        else
            return "failed";
```

And here is my Controller Method prototype:

```
        [HttpPost] 
        public IActionResult Method([FromBody] Model form)
        {...}
```

Would you happen to see what's wrong with the code?

Comment: check your baseUrl it should end with "/"

Comment: Thx @nAviD, but I checked: `RequestUri: 'https://localhost:44303/[Controller]/[Method]/'` and still 400 :(

Comment: @Hammer, did you use absolute path ? `var response2 = await Http.PostAsync("https://localhost:[port]/[controller]/[action]", stringContent2);` . And add the attribute `[ApiController]` in controller.

Comment: @Karney, I tried it. I added `[Route("[controller]")]
    [ApiController]` to my controller, and now I have a 404 not found... Strange...

Comment: Hi @Hammer, any updates about this case?

Answer (score 1):

> these requests systematically end up in 400 Bad request.

Please check you provide correct request header(s) and well-formatted data while you make request from your Blazor app to backend service.

I did a test using following code snippet with simple testing data, which work well on my side. If possible, you can create a new component and test if the code snippet can work for you.

```
var _Model = new Model { Id = 1, Name = "fehan" };

var json2 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_Model);
var stringContent2 = new StringContent(json2, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

var response2 = await Http.PostAsync("Home/Method", stringContent2);

if (response2.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var resultContent = response2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

*Model class*

```
public class Model
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Test Result

[image]

Besides, if you are making request to MVC controller action, please check if you enabled [antiforgery validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-3.1) on controller or action(s).

Comment: It works great as intended

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a **StringContent** object in your PostAsync method, but in your action you have your **Model** as a parameter.
You have two options :

1. To change your action parameter to a **StringContent**.
2. To parse the Json as your **Model** to pass it to the PostAsync method content parameter.

Regards,

Comment: Thx Gambi, but it doesn't seem to be the cause. I passed a simple string parameter, changed the controller's method to accept a string, even returned `Json(new { success = true, message = "OK" });` as a first instruction in the method, but I still get my 400 Bad Request...